# compile/interpret matlab code with one single greek character with matlab prettifier

Tags: greek, matlab-prettifier

I use the matlab prettifier package with the matlab editor option to compile a file containing matlab code in LaTeX. Question: is it possible to somehow insert a LaTeX-like command for a single character in the original matlab file/ code and interpret it accordingly via the aforementioned package while compiling in LaTeX?

Here MWE:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]{data.m}
```

Original .m code to be imported:

```
Quantity X [micrometer]

Data row 1

Data row 2


Data row N
```

I basically don't want to have micrometer in the compiled .pdf, but the actual greek character. I am aware of some "escape" options for the listings package, but I'm not quite sure how that would work in combination with the matlab prettifier package. Another possible option would be the mcode package, which enforces literate interpretations, but that package doesn't seem to produce an output that is as attractive as the one coming out of the matlab prettifier package. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that the only occurrence of the string `micrometer` in the file? If so, you could use the `literate` option.

Comment: Hi Torbjorn! Thanks for the quick reply! Yes it is. I will try that out and come back to you! Just one question: I would in that case write $\mu$ in the source .m code or how exactly would that work? Well, probably not. Just micrometer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `micrometer` only occurs one place (or, all occurrences of `micrometer` are to be replaced), you can use the `literate` option of the `listings` package. `matlab-prettifier` is based on `listings`. That is:

```
\lstinputlisting[literate={micrometer}{{$\mu\mathrm{m}$}}2]{foo.m}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[literate={micrometer}{{$\mu\mathrm{m}$}}2]{foo.m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, micrometer should actually be replaced by $\mu m$, but I have micrometer between [] in the .m code, so in the .pdf the greek-roman character actually overlaps with the square brackets. What I should be doing is actually: literate={[micrometer]}{{$\mathrm{\left[\mu m\right]}$}}1; however, matlab prettifier cannot interpret this latter option. Not sure if because of the brackets or the mathrm package therein.

Comment: @euclides True, see updated answer.

Comment: @euclides I don't really know either why the replacement doesn't work for the brackets.

Comment: works perfectly. Just one last question: the last digit in the option refers to the number of TeX characters replacing micrometer is that right?

Comment: @euclides Yes, that is correct.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your help Torbjorn!